# Background video on any device, exists or not?

Tags: android, jquery, css, background, html5-video

I have a task to make a background video that is always full-height and full-width. When I say full-height, I mean that is always ( responsive ) height as a screen height, and after scroll comes other content, footer... The other side of the problem is that video must play on all devices, from mobile to desktop.

Does something like this exist, and whether anyone had used something similar?
Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no standard for it that works on all devices, this is a good read on the subject:

http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Might be slightly outdated, if it is let me know.

Comment: It is not outdated, but that is not what I need. Because, it doesn't work on all device, second problem about is that it is a full-screen, but I need to write content below it, this type of background video naught CSS, and you can't write something below, just on the video, like in this example.

Comment: Ah sorry then, my answer was useless :)